# Javascript Coding - Good Practices/Standards

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-style

I've been working on a project (Javascript with some AJAX, JQuery, etc) and my project has gotten rather large; I'm finding myself using more and more clientside Javascript arrays, and am now considering a 2D Javascript array as well.

I know from incremental testing that my current implementation is very much manageable in terms of browser resources and performance, but was wondering if there was a general consensus as to how "heavy" a website could be in terms of Javascript memory usage and processing before it could be declared "bloated."

Also, if I'm already treading into dangerous territory by using this much storage and processing (I feel like I'm coding a rather substantial Java/C app), what is the best way to lighten the load?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that one of reasons why your code has been growing so fast is jQuery. It is really awful when it comes to larger applications, because usually everything you write is tied directly to DOM.

Comment: This is a very general question and will result in many 'it depends' answers. It would help a lot if you could provide example code and metrics.

Comment: Having run jQuery on some pretty decently sized applications, I'd argue that it has much more to do with _*how*_ you use jQuery, not whether you use jQuery.  For instance, many don't realize the cost of repeatedly running a jQuery selection (ie. $("DIV").doX(); $("DIV").doY();), and so don't think to cache queries in variables so that they can be re-used (ie. var $divs = $("DIV"); $divs.doX(); $divs.doY()).  Just doing that makes a huge difference.  But I'll agree that just using jQuery, without knowing proper practices, on a large application can be problematic.

Comment: @teresko, agreed - jQuery tends to feel extremely hackish and not at all elegant. :(
@ryan, I don't really have any specific code (that I'm allowed to reveal, at least :P), this is more of a general question to help me gauge industry standards.
@machine, I didn't know about that caching tip, thanks! Do you know of any place that documents those little tips and guidelines?

Comment: @teresko, It's your choice to tie things to the DOM, you can easily abstract the actual data away with an MVC like pattern.

Comment: MVC? Could you elaborate on that, Radu? I haven't heard of that before.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/ is a pretty good one (but take it with a grain of salt: personally I still use .each instead of "raw" for loops, despite the performance cost, and it's never had a noticeable impact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One man's "bloated" is another man's "robust".  In other words, there is no "right" answer to this question, as it depends heavily on your audience and your site.  For some sites, every millisecond of load time matters, while for others a 20 second load time is perfectly acceptable.  It really just depends.

The best advice that I can suggest is to use one of the many site performance analysis tools (eg. YSlow) to get a sense of just how slow your app actually is.  These tools can also give you a better idea of what is making your site slow; for instance, you might think it's the amount of JS code you have, but really the number of JS files (every HTTP request has a cost) might be the bigger factor.

Once you have some objective, metricable sense of how slow your site is, you can then take the time to consider your audience and determine how slow is "too slow" for them.  And once you've done that, you can then consider all of the different suggestions that YSlow (or whatever tool you choose) offers, and pick which ones (if any) make the most sense for your site.

Comment: Great points - I didn't realize how ambiguous this question was until I read some of the answers. I hadn't heard of YSlow before; I've only used JSLint before, which gives me a general idea of my code complexity but not necessarily of my overall end-user experience. A lot of my hesitation can be attributed to my relative inexperience in this field; I've only ever coded desktop applications before, so I have little context from which to judge code elegance and quality in the webapp universe. Even worse, I'm used to Java, which makes JS seem incredibly unnatural and procedural in comparison. :P

Comment: Cool!  YSlow's a good one, but there are several other good tools out there if YSlow isn't your cup of tea ... I just forget their names (I learned about them at last year's jQueryConf, but haven't used them since).  As for the "incredibly unnatural and procedural" part, I *completely* understand (as a Java coder myself).  Javascript does have a lot of really cool functional stuff that you can do that you can't do in Java though (or at least can't do without hideous inner classes).  Both languages have their strengths, and once you learn JS's you'll probably have a lot more fun with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do if you've got a lot of data is to take advantage of [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) in browsers that support it.

Other than that I can't think of a clear definition of bloat.. Does your website load quickly on modest connections? How does it do on slower browsers? If it does well in those scenarios then you're good to go.

Comment: My website loads fairly slowly, but that is due to latency issues with our current ISP. My code itself performs fine in old and new browsers alike, but my code is embedded in a webapp framework that adds huge layers of overhead, so it always seems slower than it is, and I can never know if it's my code or the framework that's being slow. Worst part is, the framework concatenates and obfuscates itself before outputting to the client, which makes it impossible for me to see which parts of the end product are mine and which parts aren't. :(

Answer (score 1):

you have a big problem that the internet connection speed is varied and that peoples hardware is varied

**OVERVIEW**
with my company we run on a 3 second system, if they page is not working in 3 seconds of it starting to download we have a problem but this could be server connection speed issue, images are to big Javascript is quite quick most of the time but if you worried about memory and speed with javascript trying to keep your script tidy helps,

**TIDY**
By tidy i mean if you have one giant js file will all your functions in or every thing in one `$(document).ready()` when its only used on 1 or 2 of your pages try splitting it up a little, but don't split it up too much as connecting to a server to download more files is a lot longer than that of running it i have script about half a MB that run fine.

**TESTING**
A good way to test that i use is to have a Windows install in Virtual Box and reduce the memory to the common amount users would have 256MB (really old), 512(old), 1024(a lot of users), 2GB+(high end users) and remember your target if your building a JS heavy site do you want to support IE6 if not then your main target is windows vista or newer and as such a minimum of 512MB of Ram is required just remember to test in the different browser FF(3.x.x, 4/5), IE(7/8/9) and chrome because different browser use different amounts of memory

**Main Causes of Bounce Rate,**
Page takes to long to load... Images are the worst cause of this

Page Crashes Browser... Javascript is looping when a certain thing happens people wont come back if there browser crashes

There will be people that always complain about JavaScript usage cater for the masses not the unique

**UPDATE**

Another good way to keep script small is to use this, also what google use for there min Script, it will drop file size (so download time) and will lower memory a little as variables name will be using less space in memory
http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/